# CORS Error in Golang with Gin after Redirect

Tags: angular, go, cors, go-gin

I'm trying to implement google oauth2 in my web server written in Go with gin. I've added two new endpoints called /google/sign-in and /google/callback. The first received the request and redirect to google auth url, and the second is called after the user selected a valid google account, verify the token and create a jwt for my internal authentication.

All is good, except it's not, because when I'm calling the first API route I get a CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=online&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx-337ka657nqlo84q6697vv2efsc2vqvm0.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&state=7e5f86fe352b4563c7d1bd62408285dcbc44e3e26a4f142bbae915279008ece6' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/google/sign-in') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is my golang code:

```
r := gin.Default()

r.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
    AllowOrigins: []string{"*"},
    AllowMethods: []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"},
    AllowHeaders: []string{"Origin", "Authorization", "Content-Type", "Content-Length", "Accept-Encoding", "X-CSRF-Token", "baggage", "sentry-trace", "X-User-Lang"},
}))

r.POST("/google/sign-in", authController.RedirectToGoogleAuthPage)
r.GET("/google/callback", authController.GoogleSignIn)
```

Auth Controller

```
func (a AuthController) RedirectToGoogleAuthPage(c *gin.Context) {
  googleAuthConfig := utils.GetGoogleAuthConfig()
  state := utils.GenerateRandomKey()
  url := googleAuthConfig.AuthCodeURL(state, oauth2.AccessTypeOnline)
  session := sessions.Default(c)
  session.Set(state, state)
  err := session.Save()
  if err != nil {
      c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, a.Errors.InternalError(err.Error()))
      return
  }
  c.Header("X-Auth-State", state)
  c.Redirect(http.StatusTemporaryRedirect, url)
}
```

In googleAuthConfig there is the callback url that is http://localhost:3000/google/callback and it's added to the google cloud oauth credentials.

I undertand that I miss the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the callback request, but how can I add that header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information in the question, you are accessing the page at `http://localhost:4200`, and sending an AJAX request to `http://localhost:3000/google/sign-in`, which redirects the request to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`. This won't work. You need a page redirect to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth` instead.

There are two choices to fix the issue:

- Modify the client code to replace the AJAX request with a form request (using a `<form action="http://localhost:3000/google/sign-in" method="POST">` element). In this case, `c.JSON` in `RedirectToGoogleAuthPage` should be replaced with something else.
- Or modify `RedirectToGoogleAuthPage` to response with a JSON content that contains the target URL to redirect to, and modify the client code to redirect the page to the target URL (with `window.location = targetURL`).

Looks like the second choice requires less change to your code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I did as you said in the second point, now it opens the google page for choosing an account, and when I click on any of then it calls localhost:3000/google/callback correctly. But then after the response I remain in the same url, so I get a black page with the web server response written in white, as always when I type manually a server link in the search bar. How can I get back to localhost:4200 that is my client? I apologize if I sound totally stupid, but I've never implemented google auth in go, I'm trying to learn

Comment: No need to apologize, we all start from somewhere. To get back to `localhost:4200`, you only need to modify the handler of `localhost:3000/google/callback` to redirect to `localhost:4200` (use `c.Redirect` this time).

Comment: But if I use c.Redirect I cannot send a json with the data I need to send to the client, or am I wrong?

Comment: You are correct. You could send the data as query in the URL. So the target URL passed to `c.Redirect` looks like this: `http://localhost:4200/path?key1=value1&key2=value2&...`.